# Password Checker in Python - unable to satisfy certain conditions

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have to write a python code that classify the strength of passwords with following conditions:
(a) A string is an **ILLEGAL** password if either:

- it is an English word (as defined in a set ENGLISH_WORDS)
- it contains any invisible character (space, tab, newline)

(b) A string is a **WEAK** password if it is not ILLEGAL and, either:

- it is less than 8 characters long.
- it is an English word followed by one or more decimal digit characters

(c) A string is a **STRONG** password if it is not ILLEGAL and:

- it contains at least 12 characters
- AND it contains at least 1 lower case letter
- AND it contains at least 1 capital letter
- AND it contains at least 1 numerical digit
- AND it contains at least 1 special character (any visible ASCII character that is not a letter or a number)

(d) A string is a **MEDIUM** password if it is not an ILLEGAL password and is not a WEAK password and is not a STRONG password.

The problem has asked me to code a function password_strength which takes the string argument and returns the strength of the function as either **ILLEGAL, STRONG, WEAK or MEDIUM**. it is to be assumed that the input password consists of only ASCII characters, that is: alphabetic letters, numerical digits, special visible characters, spaces, tabs and newlines. The special visible characters are:

~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]|/:;";<>.?

*Note: ENGLISH_WORDS is a set of common English words (all in lowercase) already imported in my notebook. I want to proceed with it without importing modules*

Here's my code:

```
def password_strength( password ):

    *#Checking if a string (password in this case) is an ILLEGAL password*
    if password.lower().strip() in ENGLISH_WORDS or " " in password or "\t" in password  or "\n" in password:
        return "ILLEGAL"

    *#Checking if a string is a WEAK Password*
    elif len(password) < 8 or (any(password[:-i].lower().strip() in ENGLISH_WORDS for i in range(1, len(password))) and any(char.isdigit() for char in password)):
        return "WEAK"

    *#Checking if a string is a STRONG Password*
    elif len(password) >= 12 and any(c.islower() for c in password) and any(c.isupper() for c in password) and any(c.isdigit() for c in password) and any(c in "~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]|\/:;\";<>.?" for c in password):
        return "STRONG"

    *#If three conditions outlined above are not met, then the string is a MEDIUM password*
    else:
        return "MEDIUM"
```

*For an input password "Secret999!", the function returns it as 'WEAK', whereas the expected answer is 'MEDIUM' *

Comment: It's weak because it begins with the English word `secret` and contains digits.

Comment: BTW, it would be more efficient if you converted the password to lower at the beginning, rather than repeatedly calling `.lower()`

Comment: @Barmar how should I proceed to get the right conditionals for the WEAK password? I am currently in a fix, and not able to get the correct solution

Comment: I think you want `and password[i:].isdigit()` inside the `any()` argument. That will test if the rest of the password after the word is all digits.

Comment: @Barmar At the cost of sounding stupid (I am new to Python), how do I incorporate it into my any() argument?

Is this correct? :
elif len(password) < 8 or (any(password[:-i].lower().strip() and password[i:].isdigit() in ENGLISH_WORDS for i in range(1, len(password))) and any(char.isdigit() for char in password)):

Comment: You should not try to do so much in each line of code (your if/elif tests).

Comment: @jarmod noted, Sir. I will ensure that readability is also there in my code moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WEAK` test looks for digits anywhere in the password. The spec says that the digits follow the word. So check if the slice of the password after the word is all digits.

```
    elif len(password) < 8 or (any(password[:-i].lower().strip() in ENGLISH_WORDS and password[-i:].isdigit() for i in range(1, len(password)))):
        return "WEAK"
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for the correct line of code. While testing it with some use-cases, for an input "secret99", the code returns MEDIUM, whereas the correct output is listed as  WEAK.  Is there something else that I should look at to get a correct result?

Comment: Sorry, `password[i:]` should have been `password[-i:]`